# Show that $\varphi(t)$ is real if and only if $F$ is symmetric for all $x$.

Tags: probability, probability-distributions

Let $X$ random variable with cumulative probability density function $F(x)$ and characteristic funtion $\varphi(t)$. So $\varphi (t)$ is real if and only if $F$ is
symmetric for all $x$.

I know that because $F$ is symmetric then  $F (−x) = 1 - F (x)$

Any sugggestions would be great!

Comment: A random variable has a **c**umulative **d**istribution **f**unction, and sometimes it may have a **p**robability **d**ensity **f**unction. I presume $F$ is the former. A small detail: notice that $F(-x)=1-F(x)$ may only hold for the points of continuity.

Answer (score 2):

$\phi$ is real iff $\phi (t)=\overline {\phi (t)}$ for all $t \in \mathbb R$. Note that the characteristic function of $-X$ is $Ee^{it (-X)}$ which is same as $\overline {\phi (t)}$. Hence  $\phi$ is real iff $X$ and $-X$ have the same characteristic function iff they have the same distribution function iff $X$ has a symmetric distribution function.